# JavaScript divide array of objects by field

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have a JSON file like this:

```
[
  {
    "type": -1,
    "name": "First Group"
  },
  {
    "type": 2,
    "name": "A"
  },
  {
    "type": 3,
    "name": "B"
  },
  {
    "type": 4,
    "name": "C"
  },
  {
    "type": -1,
    "name": "Second Group"
  },
  {
    "type": 3,
    "name": "B"
  },
  {
    "type": 4,
    "name": "C"
  },
  {
    "type": -1,
    "name": "Third Group"
  },
  {
    "type": 4,
    "name": "C"
  },
  {
    "type": 2,
    "name": "A"
  }
]
```

And I would like to divide this array of objects on many arrays, and grouping it by **"type": -1** field.

For example for current JSON I would like to get something like this:

1)

```
[
  {
    "type": -1,
    "name": "First Group"
  },
  {
    "type": 2,
    "name": "A"
  },
  {
    "type": 3,
    "name": "B"
  },
  {
    "type": 4,
    "name": "C"
  }
]
```

2)

```
[
  {
    "type": -1,
    "name": "Second Group"
  },
  {
    "type": 3,
    "name": "B"
  },
  {
    "type": 4,
    "name": "C"
  }
]
```

3)

```
[
  {
    "type": -1,
    "name": "Third Group"
  },
  {
    "type": 4,
    "name": "C"
  },
  {
    "type": 2,
    "name": "A"
  }
]
```

My question in the next:

Does it exist some function on TypeScript/JavaScript for doing this? Or need to create something specific. And if doesn't exist then how to create a better and fast solution for this?

Comment: What you want can only be done if you guarantee that the order of the objects in that array is correct, since that there is nothing in their key/values that show the group they should belong to.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you for the question. Basically, the order of the object can be random. And if object with  "type": -1 can be first or last or whatever

Comment: how do you know which parts groups together?

Comment: @NinaScholz object between "type": -1 it's will be group

Comment: then you have still an order despite your *"the order of the object can be random"*?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, if we don't have "type": -1 it's mean what we have a group but without this object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [{"type": -1,"name": "First Group"},{"type": 2,"name": "A"},{"type": 3,"name": "B"},{"type": 4,"name": "C"},{"type": -1,"name": "Second Group"},{"type": 3,"name": "B"},{"type": 4,"name": "C"},{"type": -1,"name": "Third Group"},{"type": 4,"name": "C"},{"type": 2,"name": "A"}];
const chunks = [];
let chunk = [];
arr.forEach((item) => {
 if(item.type === -1) {
  if(chunk.length) {
   chunks.push(chunk);
  }
  chunk = [];
 }
 chunk.push(item);
});
chunks.push(chunk);
console.log(chunks);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function or method for this to get the wanted groups.

You could take a new array for every found `type` equals `-1`  and take for all other types the last inserted array of the result set.

This works obviously only for sorted arrays only.

```js
var array = [{ type: -1, name: "First Group" }, { type: 2, name: "A" }, { type: 3, name: "B" }, { type: 4, name: "C" }, { type: -1, name: "Second Group" }, { type: 3, name: "B" }, { type: 4, name: "C" }, { type: -1, name: "Third Group" }, { type: 4, name: "C" }, { type: 2, name: "A" }],
    grouped = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        if (a.type === -1) {
            r.push([a]);
        } else {
            r[r.length - 1].push(a);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try following simple logic.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "type": -1,
    "name": "First Group"
  },
  {
    "type": 2,
    "name": "A"
  },
  {
    "type": 3,
    "name": "B"
  },
  {
    "type": 4,
    "name": "C"
  },
  {
    "type": -1,
    "name": "Second Group"
  },
  {
    "type": 3,
    "name": "B"
  },
  {
    "type": 4,
    "name": "C"
  },
  {
    "type": -1,
    "name": "Third Group"
  },
  {
    "type": 4,
    "name": "C"
  },
  {
    "type": 2,
    "name": "A"
  }
];

var output = [],   
    _index = 0;
    
data.forEach(function(obj){        
    if(obj.type == -1){
      output.push([obj]);
      _index++;
    } else {
     output[_index-1].push(obj);
    }
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
const collection = [{
    "type": -1,
    "name": "First Group"
  },
  {
    "type": 2,
    "name": "A"
  },
  {
    "type": 3,
    "name": "B"
  },
  {
    "type": 4,
    "name": "C"
  },
  {
    "type": -1,
    "name": "Second Group"
  },
  {
    "type": 3,
    "name": "B"
  },
  {
    "type": 4,
    "name": "C"
  },
  {
    "type": -1,
    "name": "Third Group"
  },
  {
    "type": 4,
    "name": "C"
  },
  {
    "type": 2,
    "name": "A"
  }
]

const makeReducerByTypeValue = value => (result, el, index) => {
  if (el.type === value) {
    result.sorted.push([])
    if (index > 0) result.currentIndex++
  }
  result.sorted[result.currentIndex].push(el)
  return result
}

const sorted = collection.reduce(makeReducerByTypeValue(-1), {
  currentIndex: 0,
  sorted: []
}).sorted

sorted.forEach(el => console.log(el))
```